# identifying characters from an input file in C

Tags: c, scanf

I have an input file that looks like this:

```
5  
(2,3)  
(1,4)  
(1,3)  
(3,4)  
(4,5)
```

The first number is the number of ordered pairs. I'm trying to scan in each x in (x,y) in array `x[i]`, and same for the y digit into `y[i]`.  I tried to use fscanf to take each line and put it into an array, then set `x[i]=array[1]` and set `y[i]=array[3]` for each `i`, but what I think is going on is `array[0]` is not equal to `'(`' each time it is scanned in. What would be the simplest way to scan in the x and y in `(x,y)` into `x[i]=x` and `y[i]=y` for each ordered pair?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can have random guesses at what's wrong; that's not going to help. Please show the code you are currently using.

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for your problem, the [`scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) function actually has simple pattern matching. You can tell it to look for e.g. the characters `'('`, `','` and `')'` and mix those with formatting specifiers.

Comment: Try strtok to tokenize the string.

Comment: Some day, people will notice how `scanf` (and thus the standard library) is broken for everything but the simplest of parsing tasks...

Answer (score 4):

If the numbers in the pairs are integers, you can scan them with a loop:

```
int i, res, x[number], y[number];
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    if (scanf(" (%d ,%d )", &x[i], &y[i]) != 2) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The initial space in the format will consume any whitespace characters, such as a linefeed left in the input stream by the previous `scanf`.

As suggested by KemyLand, other spaces after the `%d` will ignore spaces between the number and the `,` and `)` characters.  Ignoring spaces before the numbers is already done by the `%d` format.  But you should not add one after the `)` because it would instruct `scanf` to consume all spaces after the pair, including the `\n`, which is not a problem, but prompting for more input until a non space character has been typed, which is not what you want.

`scanf` is an old and clunky function, it can be used for quick and dirty parsing, but has many quirks and shortcomings, study the manual and look at many examples.

Comment: @sunqingyao: oops! I initially wrote a restartable loop where I only incremented `i` if `scanf` was successful, then I decided to keep it simple and stupid, and so it was.